# Angular5 material Paginator is not working

Tags: angular-material, angular5, angular-material-5

I want to use **MatPaginatorModule** in my angular t project but i am getting error:

**Can't bind to 'pageSize' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'**

**1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'pageSize' input, then verify that it is part of this module.**
...............

**html**

```
  <mat-paginator #paginator
             [pageSize]="10"
             [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
             [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
   </mat-paginator>
```

i have imported module in my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GlobalModule } from './global/global.module';
import { ProtectedModule} from './protetcted/protect-module.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
// import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    GlobalModule,
    ProtectedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i am using angular5

package.json

```
   {
  "name": "eci",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "cfenv": "^1.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kumail,
Everything looks fine from the snippets you posted.

Though this error will occur only when the required module is not linked. The only reason I could think of is that, you might not have saved `app.module.ts` file after modifications. I did follow all the steps to integrate a MatPaginatorModule in a test project and it worked. Then I mocked to include that module in `app.module.ts` but not saved the changes. This time I got the error you posted. Try saving, If you could have missed after modifying `app.module.ts` file.

Comment: can you give me the link of your demo app

Comment: yeah i saved but still have the same issue as above

Comment: you can refer to this repo: https://github.com/Rishi-RR/MatAngularDemo.git

Answer (score 0):

If the error is coming while doing testing, then the imports are needed in the test/spec file. (app.component.spec.ts)

Comment: Could you explain what is happening here?